# Does Kohana Formo prevent CSRF

Tags: kohana, csrf

Does Formo module for Kohana prevent CSRF? I haven't seen any code (tokens etc.) form protecting forms against it. So, is there any built-in solution in Formo or I have to protect forms on my own?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kohana has basic support for CSRF protection.

Check these links:

Docs: http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/2052/csrf-helper/p1

Forum: http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/Security#token

It basically means you have to put a token in your forms manually with `Security::token();`

Like this:

`echo Form::hidden('csrf', Security::token());`

Then you can check the token where you handle the form via validation:

```
$array->rules('csrf', array(
    'not_empty'       => NULL,
    'Security::check' => NULL,
));
```

Comment: I knew that, but I wanted to know if there is solution implemented in Formo (just using method or something). But nevermind :) i made my own implementation of "object forms".